# How can I get the parent of the current child?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In realtime database below.

When I have value (`"image": "firestorage"`) how can I get his parent (`"posts"`)?

How can I get the parent of the current child?

```
{

    "posts": {
      "name": "hemy",
      "description": "soft,TRAVEL",
      "address": "SANAA,INDIA",
      "image": "firestorage",
      "userid": "1"
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you are trying to do is query snapshots depending on value present meaning, you want to find all parents where a child has value "image" = "firestorage"

You can simply create a query and use it,

```
Query searchAllQuery = postsRef
            .orderByChild("image");

searchAllQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        // filter your data here

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: in firebaserecyclerview 
the current data in holder 
i have child and his values 
i wand use once of values to get parent root

in ex ...i have a child named (posts), containing a child's (name)
I want to use this child (name)programmatically to find  (posts)parent

Comment: can't paste here did you have any social media

Comment: Paste it in your question

Answer (score 0):

> You should call the getKey() method from dataSnapshot

```
 final Query userQuery = mRef.orderByChild("name");

 userQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    map.clear();
    //Get the parent from the datasnapshot
    String myParentNode = dataSnapshot.getKey(); // parent node
    for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
       String key = child.getKey().toString(); //child node
       String value = child.getValue().toString();
       map.put(key,value);
    }
```

Comment: i dont know what you are doing with your code so here is simple example for you hope this will help.